# Django: Get row based on maximum value of a foreign key field value

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two models

```
class Status(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    rank = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class MyModel(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    entry_date = models.DateField()

--- Status table ---
id   |   name     |   rank 
1    |   poor     |   1
2    |   below avg|   2
3    |   avg      |   3
4    |   above avg|   4
5    |   good     |   5


--- MyModel table ---
user   |  category | status_id | entry_date
user1  |  A        | 1         | ..
user1  |  A        | 2         | ..
user1  |  A        | 3         | ..
user1  |  B        | 2         | ..
```

For a given user I want to get the maximum ranked status for each category. So for user1, i need the following two rows

```
user   |  category | status_id | entry_date
user1  |  A        | 3         | ..
user1  |  B        | 2         | ..
```

How can I achieve this? I tried `MyModel.objects.annotate(max_rank=Max('status__rank')).filter(status__rank=F('max_rank'))`
but it throws an "Unknown column 'myapp_status.rank' in 'having clause'".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you want to group by user and category, i think you need something like

```
 MyModel.objects.values('user', 'category' 
     ).annotate(max_rank=Max('status__rank'))
```

since there may be several entries with max rank, i don't think you can get the `entry_date` from an aggregation query like this

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values) for more